# Add file (graphic) to directory only if not existing

Tags: r, purrr

I'm printing multiple graphics overtime and want to not reprint or duplicate those I've already printed previously.

What my code looks like now is:

```
library(tidyverse)

 split_df <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)

  plots <- map(split_df,  ~ggplot(.x, aes(x = hp,
                                y = wt)) +
                  geom_line() +
                  theme_minimal(12) 
                  )
```

And to print them off:

```
print_graphs <- function(plot){

    plot %>% 
      walk2(.x = plot, .y = names(plot),
            ~ggsave(filename = paste0("./", .y, ".jpg"), #change to your directory
                    plot = .x, width = 9, height = 6))

  }

print_graphs(plots)
```

I'm thinking along the lines of comparing this result into the `print_graphs()` function:

```
existing <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(list.files("./current_dir"))
```

But can't figure it out into a loop, or ideally just within the `walk2()`.

thanks in advance!

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-caching.html

Comment: @joran for the moment I have two functions, one for plotting, one for printing - should I combine both of these into a single function you're saying, or have a check prior to the ggplot()? because I would like all graphics stored each time I run it, in case I need to reprint all